# MVC - Sending Pivot Results to Client Page When Model Property Names Cannot Be Known

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC 5 app in which I'd like to send the results of a server side Pivot query to a page. The problem is that, given the nature of Pivot results, I have no idea what the column names will be, and, therefore, I have no idea what my model property names will be. I'm curious if it's even possible to do what I want to do. If so, how are the model property names, which won't be known until run time, dealt with?

One solution to this would be some sort of reporting tool, but I'd rather not go that route. I can handle the Pivot query easily enough. I just don't know how to send the results to a web page. Maybe there is something obvious I'm overlooking?

Comment: An example of the data and your page layout would be useful :)

Comment: Why does the page layout, or example data, matter? I want to display an HTML table containing pivoted data, which means an unknown number of columns and unknown, until runtime, column names. HOwever, the columns will contain date values. I just have no way of knowing how many or what the dates will be.

Comment: Any example would be useful. Normally an example of what you have tried is expected on SO (otherwise you tend to receive sarcastic links pointing to recruitment sites) :)